# How was Valk able to process fluids given his condition?

Tags: forsaken-skies

The character Valk was burned badly in Forsaken Skies, and the author describes how he drank alcohol and other fluids through a small hole he opened in his visor to prevent others from seeing his badly damaged face.

> *Valk sipped carefully at his liquor. No one had been able to find a
>   straw for him, so he made do with a length of tubing from a vapor
>   injector that still smelled like coolant - ably masked by the creosote
>   taste of the scotch. He tried to savor the alcohol, though it didn’t
>   taste as good as it used to, back before his accident. Nothing ever
>   did.*

Given what we later learn of *the severity of his condition*, how did his body process these fluids?

> i.e. Why didn't the suit slosh when he walked because of fluid puddling in his suit? I can understand how he could be convinced to not notice he never eats anything, but he explicitly drinks several times in the books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not explicitly stated, but the standard military suits "take care of that", presumably by processing the fluid into removable (and replaceable) pads or through some sort of handwavium fluid-into-air solution. It would seem likely that Valk's suit functions in much the same way.

> *Valk stopped pacing. Instead he folded his arms and bobbed up and down
>   like he needed to urinate.*
>
> ***One of the great compensations for the dreariness of Naval service,
>   Maggs had always found, was that your suit took care of such things
>   without ever requiring you to think about them.*** He frowned at the big
>   fool, then went back to his studied attempt at expending no energy
>   whatsoever.

The alternative is that since we know that he's being shown an alternative version of reality, he's simply tricked by his programming into periodically "*urinating*" when in fact he's just emptying a bladder/stomach (containing whatever fluids he's ingested) into the toilet.

Comment: ok, I can accept that if the standard suits take care of urination et al, that his might have been built with that opening designed to keep up the facade but simply redirect that fluid directly to the urination system. thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @simpleuser - If it was me, I'd just muck with his perception. It actually seems like the easier option. Make him think he's drinking when all he's doing is putting the straw in his mouth.

Comment: but that would be really obvious to those drinking with him, so I discounted it

Comment: @simpleuser - I used to work with a guy who'd "nurse" a drink all night long, to the point that I thought he might actually be tee-total on the sly.